# Scala - Extend Generic Type Parameter

Tags: scala, generics, nested-generics

Sorry if this is a duplicate. Had trouble finding with some basic searches.

If I have

```
trait Container[T] { data: T }
```

I'm trying to have a trait extend Container such that data is a Traversable[T].

Would the following do that, and what does it mean/how would you read it?

```
trait Extension[T] extends Container[Traversable[T]]
```

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your problem. Yes, `Extension[T]` is a `Container[Traversable[T]]`, which means it can only hold `Traversable[T]` as `data`.

Comment: Perfect. Then I think I'm all good! Thanks. When I said "how would you read it", your comment answered that part so thanks

Comment: I'm converting this to an answer so you can mark your question as resolved then.

Comment: sounds good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Extension[T] is a Container[Traversable[T]], which means it can only hold Traversable[T] as data.

Note that you might want to define `Extension[+T]` instead of `Extension[T]` (and do this for `Container` as well). This will means that `Extension[Cat]` is a subclass of `Extension[Animal]`.